# PHP: Can iterator_to_array() throw an exception on a MongoCursor

Tags: php, exception, mongodb, iterator, cursor

Can using `iterator_to_array()` on a `MongoCursor` instance throw an exception in PHP 5.3? In other words, do I need to wrap `iterator_to_array()` calls on `MongoCursor` instances in try-catch statements or not?

e.g.,

```
$mongo = new Mongo();
$mongo_db = $mongo['my_database'];
$mongo_coll = $mongo_db['my_collection'];

// This

$cursor = $mongo_coll->find();
$documents = iterator_to_array($cursor);

// Versus this.

$cursor = $mongo_coll->find();
try {
    $documents = iterator_to_array($cursor);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iterator_to_array()` can throw exceptions because it calls [next()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.next.php).

Answer (score 0):

I think the first comment as of now on this page http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.queries.php will be of interest to you, but don't know if it will be first when you view it so here is the deal.

You can check if the cursor is valid by using `$cursor->valid()`.
And the comment says that you might have to rewind the cursor after receiving it, as it is sometime not rewound when received.

```
...
$cursor = $mongo_coll->find();
$cursor->rewind();
if ($cursor->valid()) {
    $documents = iterator_to_array($cursor);
}
```

The advantage to the above try catch block is that the try catch block might throw the exception while you could have used the cursor when the cursor was actually valid.

Comment: don't believe everything you read in comments at php.net. actually $cursor->valid() will AWLAYS return FALSE immediatelly after cursor is created, because actual things only happen when you call next() first time (which is what rewind() basically do).

Comment: Ok I get it, the `$cursor` will only turn into an iterable object once `$cursor->next()` is called but also when `$cursor->rewind()` is called, which is what the OP desires.

Comment: your code doesn't guarantee iterator_to_array() won't throw. this is what OP's question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Find method returns Traversable object or throws an exception.

Iterator_to_array is accepting Traversable object.

Exception should appear only if something really bad happens in Mongo driver or in Mongo during iteration. Maybe disconnection.